# OpenLayers: creating a minimal map

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm sorry for this basic question. But I'm pretty new with OperLayers. As a first step, I want to show the OpenStreetMap which is already zoomed on Vienna. The code displays a map with an OpenStreetMap layer centered on Nottingham. Instead of Nottingham I want Vienna.

[The code of Nottingham](http://imageshack.com/a/img196/1521/kba2.png)

Comment: So... you're *essentially* asking "what are the coordinates of Vienna?" What does the question have to do with OpenLayers or any of the mentioned technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I (as @kryger) don't understand what the exact problem is (I hope you don't ask at SO others just for a pair of coordinates?), I will try an answer:

You can have a look at the source of this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm.html
The only thing you have to modify are the startup coordinate pair:

```
...
new OpenLayers.LonLat(16.3866, 48.1913).transform(...)
...
```

You can find this coordinates, if you browse OSM and have a look at the URL http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/17328659#map=12/48.1913/16.3866

---

Maybe it's just an misunderstanding and don't call me rude, but every support community expects minimal work by the questioner. A study of http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/ seems to be not to hard esp. for new users. Anyway have fun with Openlayers :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I dont call you rude not at all. The problem is solved. I´m used to work on a virtual box in my computer since the main operating system is windows. Even though i typed the coordinate of Vienna, the map didnt just show up. I thought there is something missing in the code or problem with projections of the coordinates whatever. I must have problem with virtual box. because i downloaded a html editor in the main operating system of the computer and everything is fine.

Comment: The same code i typed which is didnt work in virtual machine, has been working now in the windows. 
view: new ol.View2D({
      center: ol.proj.transform([16.36, 48.21], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857' ),
      zoom: 14 
I´m exactly try to get help from the documents which you have given the link. Thanks again for your concern The question was never the coordinate of Vienna. But i need to fix the virtual maschine problem.

Comment: NP, but it's always a good idea to provide such informations in your requests.